# Static files show in test server but not in production

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I have a problem with my Django app not finding static files. When I try to look up the file in the test server, it shows up, on the console I get:

```
[01/Feb/2022 21:34:25] "GET /static/2022/2022-01-12/20220630.pdf HTTP/1.1" 200 295223
```

But when I try to look at the file in the production server I get this in the error log:

```
2022/02/01 21:34:08 [error] 6769#6769: *317 open() "/home/pi/Django/my_project/static/2022/2022-01-12/20220630.pdf" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.178.**, server: ********, request: "GET /static/2022/2022-01-12/20220630.pdf HTTP/1.1", host: "*******", referrer: "http://myraspi4/documents/doc_show/261"
```

In the settings file I have static directories set up like this:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    '/mnt/ssd/doc_storage',
]
```

Permissions are -rwxrwxrwx on all files. Other files in other subdirectories show up no problem. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have r-x permissions on all the parent folders path? I mean on each static/2022/2022-01-12/ folder you need r-x permissions.

Comment: Did you run [`collectstatic`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/#deployment)? Static files are automatically served during testing (when `DEBUG = True` but not in prod.